# Output is correct but program crashes after printing the output everytime

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I'm implementing preorded binary tree traversal without using recursion.
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

struct node{

int data;
node *left;
node *right;

};

node *getNewNode(int data){   //method for creating new node

node *newNode = new node();
newNode->data=data;
newNode->left=newNode->right = NULL;
return newNode;

}

node *Insert(node *root , int data){     //Method for insert new data in tree

if(root == NULL){
    root = getNewNode(data);
}
else if(data>root->data){
    root->right = Insert(root->right,data);
}
else{
    root->left = Insert(root->left,data);
}

return root;

}

void Print(node *root){  //Method for preorder traversal with recursion

if(root == NULL){
    return;
}

 cout<<root->data<<" ";
Print(root->left);

Print(root->right);

}

void preOdr(node *root){  //Without recursion

stack<node*> stk;
cout<<root->data<<" ";

do{
    a:
    if(!(root->right==NULL&&root->left==NULL)){
        if(root->right!=NULL){
             stk.push(root->right);
        }
        if(root->left!=NULL){
             stk.push(root->left);
        }
    }
    cout<<stk.top()->data<<" ";
    root=stk.top();
    stk.pop();
    goto a;
}
while(!stk.empty());



}

int main(){

node *root = NULL;
root = Insert(root,10);
root = Insert(root,6);
root = Insert(root,15);
root = Insert(root,3);
root = Insert(root,9);
root = Insert(root,11);
root = Insert(root,17);
root = Insert(root,11);
root = Insert(root,62);
root = Insert(root,135);
root = Insert(root,30);
root = Insert(root,98);
root = Insert(root,117);
root = Insert(root,176);

Print(root);
cout<<endl;
preOdr(root);

return 0;
}
```

In my program I've also created method for preorder traversal using recursion to verify the output given by non-recursive method which is `Print()`.

In non-recursive method, first I'm printing the root, than pushing the right and left child of that node (If any) to the stack respectively. After this I am popping item from the stack and repeat the above process till the stack is not empty.

When I run this code, It gives output correctly, but crashes after that. I can't understand what is the problem in the method named `preOrd()`. I've attached full code for better understanding.

Comment: Get rid of the `goto` in `preOdr` It serves no purpose and you end up creating an infinite loop inside of your do {} while()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `preOrd()` function is screwed.

### 1.Don't use goto

First you have a `goto` at the end of the loop, jumping right at the beginning of the loop.  This prevents the `while` condition from being verified and causes a loop for ever.  Once the stack is empty, it will try to `pop`/`top` which causes UB (here the crash) !

Every time you're tempted to use `goto`, think twice !  Prefer `break` to interrupt a loop, or `continue` to cycle properly.  This would avoid these kind of issues in the future.

Quote of the day: *"goto - the infamous goto." - [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html)*

### 2.Then revise logic of the loop

If you just comment out the `goto`, it will work better, but stop after the second level (this time without crash). Obviously, you don't push everything needed on the stack.

Here a revised version:

```
void preOdr(node *root){  //Without recursion

    stack<node*> stk;
    stk.push(root);           // put the root not on th stack and 
                              // then process it like the others
    while (!stk.empty()) {
        root=stk.top();
        stk.pop();
        cout<<root->data<<" ";  // get and show top of stack
        if(root->right)         // then push the childern 
            stk.push(root->right);
        if(root->left)    
            stk.push(root->left);
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/2kCriu)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a goto keyword that takes you back to the beginning of that code block, which is the purpose of the while at the end. It's a loop inside your loop that has no check.